# Repeating frame contents

Tags: beamer, loops

Supposing that I'll use always two blocks on each frame.

Then, I'd like to have a simple way to do the following, without copy/paste procedure:

On each frame (except the first one),

- the first block should be the second block from the previous frame.

So I guess that something similar to the code below would be possible and helpful:

```
\begin{frame}
% code to call the second block from the previous frame
\begin{block} % the new block, to be used again on the next frame
\end{block}
\end{frame}
```

If it's possible to use some overlays it would be nice.

Any idea?

Comment: I'm working on a solution based on the `environ` package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a solution without manual intervention; `\dupbox` makes all the job; initially you define the initial contents and then simply invoke it with the new text; `\dupbox` has also an optional argument allowing you to specify a title for the block:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usecolortheme{crane}

\newcommand\dupbox[2][]{%
\begin{block}{\duptitle}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\duptext
\end{minipage}
\end{block}
\begin{block}{#1}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
#2
\end{minipage}
\end{block}
\gdef\duptext{#2}
\gdef\duptitle{#1}
}

\gdef\duptext{Initial text}
\gdef\duptitle{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\dupbox[Optional title]{Some text for frames one and two}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\dupbox{Another test text for frames two and three with some math:
\[a=b.\]
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\dupbox[A simple TikZ drawing]{\tikz{\fill[blue] (0\linewidth,0) circle (13pt);
\fill[orange] (6,0) circle (13pt);}
}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\dupbox{Even more text}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect!! If I could I would give you +10. It was a simple but genial solution. Thanks so much.

Comment: How about the block titles?

Comment: @Jubobs, I'm trying to do this using a second argument `#2`.

Comment: @Sigur please see my updated answer for a version allowing to have titles.

Comment: @Jubobs your wish is my command ;-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, great! How it knows that the first argument is an optional argument? Also, why to use empty brackets `[]` on the code, after the number of arguments?

Comment: @Sigur the extra pair of square brackets is precisely telling TeX that the first argument is optional; leaving it empty (as in this case) simple indicates that no default value will be used. The syntax for defining a command with an optional argument is `\newcommand[<number>][<default value for #1>]{<do someting with the parameters>}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That's great! Perfect answer.

Answer (score 5):

Like that?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\only<1>{\begin{block}{First} block \end{block}}
\only<1,2>{\begin{block}{Second} block  \end{block}}
\only<2,3>{\begin{block}{Third} block \end{block}}
\only<3>{\begin{block}{4th}  block \end{block}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, the result would be the same. But your code produces only one frame with many slides. I'd like to be able to use other frames.

Comment: Well, this has been solved already by Gonzalo Medina, just add that another solution could be use external files and include twice with `\input{file}`.